# Using \href inside \footnote

Tags: hyperref, footnotes

Somehow, the following code is not compiling:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{medium-blue}{rgb}{0,0,1}
\hypersetup{colorlinks, urlcolor={medium-blue}}

\begin{document}
Text\footnote{\href{http://google.co.in}}
\end{document}
```

If I replace \href with \url, the code seems to work. However, I insist on using \href because I like its output better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is nothing to do with the footnote. The `\href` macro takes two arguments. The first is the link destination, and the second is what's displayed.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{medium-blue}{rgb}{0,0,1}
\hypersetup{colorlinks, urlcolor={medium-blue}}

\begin{document}
Text\footnote{Click \href{http://google.co.in}{here}.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Gosh! I have been using \href for so long now. Yet, I completely forgot about the second argument this time. I had myself convinced that this has something to do with the \footnote command. Thanks!

Comment: Do you suggest that I delete/remove this question since it kinda wrong, misleading and silly?

Comment: @vkarve --- It's entirely up to you.

Comment: @vkarve, I just stumbled upon this. It was of no help to me. Maybe, yes, you could have the question deleted.

Comment: Actually \href{}{} does not work in the footnote if the link includes a %.

Comment: @user2392762 --- I suggest asking a new question about this, as it's a separate issue. Also, if you can provide a working link that contains a `%` symbol then it will be easier for others to test.

Comment: Or a #, seemingly, especially if the second argument is a \nolinkurl

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that special characters are properly escaped. For example:

- `#`, `%`, `&`
- or accidentally encoded special characters like round brackets `(`, `)` .

```tex
This \footnote{
\href{https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load\#page-data}
{SvelteKit docs: Loading data - Page data}
}
That \footnote{
\href{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructivism_(philosophy_of_education)}
{philo of edu with round brackets}
}
Those \footnote{
\href{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructivism_\%28philosophy_of_education\%29}
{philo of edu with encoded round brackets}
}
(encoded with JS function \verb|URIComponent|)
```

The produced result will look like this:
[image]